# Will there be any performance impact if I replace the firebase unique key with some customized ones?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

For firebase realtime database, every time I call `push()` to add something, there will be a unique 28-digit key generated.

My use case is I am storing my blog data into the database. Blog object has title, content, author fields. Like Below

```
Blog {
  title: "",
  content: "",
  author: ""
}
```

When I `push(blog)` into Firebase, say it will generate a unique key something like `PxbEfWQhGP3NTU6HfHuVZfAV4017jcuzSpTnHvhLNXbo`. I can use it to construct the URL to be `mywebsite.com/blog/PxbEfWQhGP3NTU6HfHuVZfAV4017jcuzSpTnHvhLNXbo` to access the blog page. The blogId can be read from the URL and use it to read the blog content from the database. But few reasons I don't like this UR, it's not SEO friendly and reader friendly.

I am thinking to replace the unique key with the blog title, it will be like `mywebsite.com/blog/this-is-my-first-blog-1ad92b25dd`. I will append some random string in the end to less chance to be conflicted.

By doing so, I need to have a place to store the title to blogId mapping. Something like below:

```
titleToId
  "this-is-my-first-blog-1ad92b25dd"
    blogId: "PxbEfWQhGP3NTU6HfHuVZfAV4017jcuzSpTnHvhLNXbo"
  "yeah-i-did-it-1ad9321ef"
    blogId: "is37nLeQg1dslZPMLpdARyxIMzh2Lj6cRUNkq00i3JB8"
  "not-sure-if-it-works-1ad92523414"
    blogId: "B2kcEwTI02wFJXjBWiDZlDFIzJ502xcAY4qQLyPExzViw"
...
```

So whenever I try to open a blog, I get the title from URL, then I read the database `titleToId` to get the actual `blogId`, then I use the `blogId` to read the blog's content.

But I have some concern on the performance. As we replace the unique key with the blog title. Once the dataset in `titleToId` gets larger, say we have 100 million entries. Will the database read performance degrade too much? In my case, can I set up some index to speed up the read?

Comment: Is there any reason for making a lookup? Couldn't you use `this-is-my-first-blog-1ad92b25dd` as the node key for your blog node?

Comment: Hmm, that's a good one. Why I have to do one extra step??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will be no performance impact.  It doesn't really matter much what you use for the unique ID string, as long as it's unique and under 768 bytes long.  There is no need to create any indexes for the names of database notes.

Comment: Such great news Doug! Can you explain a little bit what will happen behind the scene? What algorithm Firebase uses to locate the particular key? Thanks!

Comment: It can't be boiled down to a simple algorithm.  The way cloud services scale is rather complex.  You can be sure that it's a constant time lookup, though.

Comment: That's more than enough. Thanks Doug!